# Moment.js locale dates won't change

Tags: angular, momentjs

I try to translate months to German, but I still get English months. I've read all the forums, but still don't get the problem fixed.

```js
import moment from 'moment/src/moment';
import localization from 'moment/locale/de';

ngOnInit() {
    moment.locale('de', localization);
    console.log(moment.locales()); // output is 'de'
    console.log(moment.months()) // output is 'January', 'February', ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't specify the second argument from `locale` method:

```
moment.locale('de');
```

**Edit**

In your Module, you should register the Locales, import `MatMomentDateModule` and declare the LOCAL_ID :

```
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [MatMomentDateModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' },
  ],
  ...,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this changes nothing.

Comment: I checked how I do and I forgot to mention that you need to register the locale in your Angular Module.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I added this to my code, and removed the second import. But now the only locale logged is 'en'.

Comment: Updated my answer adding MomentAdapter and Locale provider

Comment: I got it working! I removed the node_modules/moment/src folder and updated the import to import * as moment from 'moment';

Thank you for our work!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Note: MatMomentDateModule import is only useful if you use Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes have a look at

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mb2emg

Solution: explicitly import locales in addition to 'moment':

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/de';
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me I have done the following changes:-

```
moment.locale('de');
alert(moment.months()); // output is german months
```